# System.Windows.Point vs custom Point struct in c#

Tags: c#, struct, point

I've a question that may seem dumb a little. I'm going to read and handle lots of 2D point coordinates in my program. Should I use the default `Point` struct in `System.Windows.Point` or should I use my own struct like this?

```
public struct_2DPoint
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
}
```

Will I save memory using the second method?

Comment: `System.Windows.Point` has two double members the same as yours, so no it won't save memory using your own.

Comment: Thanks, What about all the methods and other things it has? They won't have any effect on memory usage?

Comment: Well the extra methods will take up some space at runtime, so it will be slightly more expensive, but each individual point will be the same size (16 bytes).

Comment: @Vahid, unless your application is targeting systems with really low memory like <512MB, you need not worry about memory usage. IMHO, processing power and storage are cheap these days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the System.Windows.Point.

Reason for my recommendation:

1. Many built-in functions are available just in case you need them later in code
2. Readily Inter-operable with System.Windows.Geometry and other types which you may use
3. From a '**maintenance**' point of view, developers other than you who look at the code will easily understand what is happening and what else can be done.

Comment: Thanks KSK, I see that it is sealed. So let's say I have a `Point` and I also need `GridPoint` that derives from Point? Will I need to wrap Point in this case?

Comment: Yes, that is pretty much the idea when you want to extend something that's 'sealed' for some unknown reason. But good question.

Comment: Thanks KSK, I think I got all what I needed to proceed.